# Edit Popup Dialog from AutoComplete SWT Combo Widget

Tags: java, autocomplete, combobox, widget, swt

im trying to edit the Popup which displays when i type something in my Combo. I tried to extend the ContentProposalAdapter, but it seems more complicated i needed...I want to display a Table instead of a simple String list in the Popup, so is there any chance to do this or do i have to write my own ContentProposalAdapter :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after watching into the SWT Snippets from http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/. I just write my own class who takes an SWT Text and add some Listeners, a ModifyListener opens a new Dialog (without any button or something else). The dialog holds a TableViewer and ViewFilter